# homebrew upgrade vim package failed: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat

Tags: vim, homebrew

In my Mac notebook, cannot using homebrew to upgrade vim.
I forgot how did I install vim last time.

```
➜ brew upgrade vim
Updating Homebrew...
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
vim 8.2.1400 -> 8.2.1600
==> Upgrading vim 8.2.1400 -> 8.2.1600
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/sqlite-3.33.0.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/78566572373e0010a52729c1b41f7503f4e86acc67e7a37bafe091a6ddc36147?r
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/vim-8.2.1600.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Installing dependencies for vim: sqlite
==> Installing vim dependency: sqlite
==> Pouring sqlite-3.33.0.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
sqlite is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have sqlite first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find sqlite you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.33.0: 11 files, 4MB
==> Installing vim
==> Pouring vim-8.2.1600.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
Error: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - /usr/local/bin/vimdiff
```

```
➜ which vim
/usr/bin/vim

~
➜ which vimdiff
/usr/bin/vimdiff

➜ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun  5 2020 21:30:37)
```

Comment: Sqlite a dependency of Vim?

Comment: That's not the root cause of this error.

Comment: And that was a comment, not an answer or a solution. Try homebrew's issue tracker.